# is it possible to search kubernetes config by key

Tags: kubernetes

is it possible to search kubernetes `service/deployment...` by config key. For example, I want to list which `service/deployment...` contains this config:

```
externalTrafficPolicy:Local
```

without search, I have to check the service config one by one.

Comment: Use `--output` or `--template` (with `kubectl get`) to output the `spec.externalTrafficPolicy` then `grep`.

Comment: I have tried this command: `kubectl get svc -o yaml -n reddwarf-pro |grep "externalTrafficPolicy"`, it can find out the context. is it contains better way?

Comment: Better use json output with jq

Comment: It should be straightforward to write a script using the Kubernetes API to do this.  Have you tried already?  What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do that would be to get all services of all namespaces as json and use jq to select those with the required policy and print their namespace/name, like:

`kubectl get svc -A -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.spec.externalTrafficPolicy == "Local") | .metadata.namespace + "/" + .metadata.name'`

this will print a list of `<namespace>/<service-name>` like:

```
my-namespace-one/service-one
my-other-namespace/another-service
[...]
```

You can use this to check against any kind of config/label/... in any kind of resource.